# ios UITableView reloads data when scroll down to bottom rows

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

I've implemented a pull down to refresh that sits above my UITableView.

However, UITableView also has a default setting where if you push up (to reveal rows at the bottom of the table), it also reloads the table data. Since I already have pull down to refresh, I want to disable this. How do I do that?

Thanks!

EDIT: I want to load all the rows of the UITableView at once, not just the visible rows, because I'm not loading too many rows anyway.

Comment: "UITableView also has a default setting where if you push up (to reveal rows at the bottom of the table), it also reloads the table data" really?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's "reloading" the cells. If they have been dequeued, then they are being loaded. If you don't want those cells there, then why do you have them in the first place? If you scroll them off the screen they normally get dequeued to improve performance of the tableview. If you don't want this behaviour, then you may not want to dequeue your cells, but tableview performance could be drastically affected.